# how to send argument to ESP8266WebServer objects on function

Tags: programming, c++, c, sketch

this probably simple thing to do however I can't think of a way to pass argument to function call

```
ESP8266WebServer server ( 80 );

void toggleRelayOne() {
  char temp[400];
  String msg = "";
  if (relay1 == 0) {
    relay1 = 1;
    msg = "Light is turned on";
  }
  else {
    relay1 = 0;
    msg = "Light is turned off";
  }


  digitalWrite (5, relay1); //GPIO 5 // Relay 1
  snprintf ( temp, 400,
             "<html>\
  <head>\
    <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5'/>\
    <title>NodeMCU DHT11 Sensor and Relay Board</title>\
    <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=../'>\
    </head>\
  <body>\
  %d .</body>\
  </html>"
             , 1);
  server.send ( 200, "text/html", temp );
}

void setup ( void ) {

  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin ( 9600 );
  WiFi.begin ( ssid, password );
  Serial.println ( "" );
  // Wait for connection
  while ( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ) {
    delay ( 500 );
    Serial.print ( "." );
  }

  Serial.println ( "" );
  Serial.print ( "Connected to " );
  Serial.println ( ssid );
  Serial.print ( "IP address: " );
  Serial.println ( WiFi.localIP() );

  if ( MDNS.begin ( host ) ) {
    Serial.println ( "MDNS responder started" );
  }
  MDNS.addService("http", "tcp", 80);
  server.on ( "/", handleRoot );
  server.on("/relay1", toggleRelayOne);
  server.begin();
  Serial.println ( "HTTP server started" );
}
```

in the above function where I am calling `toggleRelayOne` using `server.on("/relay1", toggleRelayOne);` I want to be able to pass relay id so I can use same function to toggle multiple relays.

Comment: server.on ( "/", handleRoot );
why it used??

Comment: When a user tries to navigate to `"/"` I call a function  `handleRoot` . This function reads the data from sensors connected to ESP826.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `server.arg()` to pass commands from the web as GET params:

`digitalWrite (5, relay1);`

becomes

`digitalWrite (server.arg("pin").toInt(), relay1);`

where the URL is something like `http://192.168.1.5/relay1?pin=15`

Of course, the rest of your code probably needs to be adapted to manage the extra states, read/write all in one http call, etc.